# Automatic Logout Using Php

Tags: php, angularjs

If user 'A' is logged in some credentials into a Mobile App.for ex,
username: user
password: user
and user 'B' tries to login using same credentials provided above.Then on successful login of user 'B',user 'A' session must be destroyed and should be automatically logged out from the Mobile App.

Comment: please specify what issue you are facing with the related code.

Comment: On authenticating User 'B',User 'A' session should be destroyed and he should be logged out of the App i.e, redirect him to login page directly.

Comment: You simply destroy the other user's session/invalidate their token, and the next request that user attempts will be rejected and the app can go to the login state. If you need that to happen immediately, you need some way to push notifications to the client, e.g. using SSE or web sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user logs in, generate a token and store it somewhere associated with the client (e.g. in a store in the app, or in a session) and somewhere associated with the account (e.g. in the users table of your database).

Only store one token in the latter of those two places.

When you get a request, in addition to whatever other checking you do to see if the user is a logged in user, check that the token sent by their client matches the *current* one stored against their account.